# How compiler knows which lambda to use in submit(Callable<T> task) or submit(Runnable task) in ExecutorService?

Tags: java, lambda, type-inference

> submit() method accepts both Runnable and callable as parameters. but
> it returns Future when we send callable interface as a parameter.

So when just lambda posted

```
() -> {}
```

how compiler knows which functional interface to use? Callable or Runnable? AFAIK the compiler is not smart enough to analyse is the expression return something or not, or am I wrong?

Comment: `() -> {}` simply doesn't "look" `Callable`.

Comment: "AFAIK the compiler is not smart enough to analyse is the expression return something or not" Try declaring a method to return `String`, and then proceed to not return anything from that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda expression `() -> {}` is not compatible with `Callable<T>` for any `T`, whereas it *is* compatible with `Runnable`. Therefore the `Runnable` overload is chosen.

Sections [15.27.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3) and [15.27.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2) of the JLS explains why this is the case.

> A lambda expression is compatible in an [...] invocation context [...] with a target type T if T is a functional interface type (§9.8) and the expression is congruent with the function type of the ground target type derived from T.

The ground target type of `Callable<T>` here is still `Callable<T>`. Let's see what "congruent" means:

> A lambda expression is congruent with a function type if all of the following are true:
>
> [...]
>
> - If the function type's result is a (non-void) type `R`, then either i) the lambda body is an expression that is compatible with `R` in an assignment context, or ii) the lambda body is a value-compatible block, and each result expression (§15.27.2) is compatible with `R` in an assignment context.

A "value-compatible block" is defined as:

> A block lambda body is value-compatible if it cannot complete normally (§14.21) and every return statement in the block has the form `return Expression;`.

Also:

> In a value-compatible block lambda body, the *result expressions* are any expressions that may produce an invocation's value. Specifically, for each statement of the form `return Expression ;` contained by the body, the `Expression` is a result expression.

So the claim that "the compiler is not smart enough to analyse if the expression return something or not" is false. Any Java compiler would need to follow what the spec says, and analyse whether the block completes normally (roughly means finishes running without reaching a `return` or `throw` statement).

In the case of `() -> {}`. there are no return statements, so the block always complete normally.